# Right Regression for 2 binominal IVs and one metric DV

Tags: r, statistics, regression

My independet variables are binominal (gender and posture)
but my dependent varibale is interval scaled (it's seven steps Likert scale)

What is the right regression model for this? And how do I apply it in R?

Thanky you for any advice

Comment: Please provide some minimal & representative sample data for us to work with. It sounds like ordinal (logistic) regression (e.g. using `polr::polr`) might be what you're after.

Comment: As I understand the posting, there are four possible combinations of input: 0-0, 0-1, 1-0, and 1-1. That would indicate only four possible output states, one for each input combination.

Answer (score -1):

`For the constellation 2 binominal IVs and one metric DV, it is okay to use a simple Linear model like `lm` in R.

Comment: This is *not* the correct approach if your response variable is an ordinal variable (as per your original question, where your response is measured on the Likert scale).